# Storing CSV dataset in a block/Genesis Block of a Blockchain and using Time-Series prediction

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, machine-learning

I want to store a CSV dataset in blockchain and apply Time Series Prediction on the basis of the provided dataset. Can we add the predicted value back into the dataset to use it for the next time prediction? how can I achieve this with any blockchain like Hyperledger-Fabric?

Comment: The EVM has a key-value storage that you could use to store data. You will need to implement time prediction using a contract.